# measure for jobs/complaints ratio

Tags: descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics, measurement, rating, percentage

I have a number of jobs in a database which can receive complaints. A job can receive several complaints and a job has an associated supplier. I would like to identify the worst performing suppliers. This should be made relative to the number of jobs executed. For example, one job executed by supplier X that resulted in one complaint leading to a job complaint ration of 100% is not as bad as if supplier Y executed 1000 jobs but received 1000 + complaints. Is there a suitable formula/KPI for my scenario? Thanks.

Comment: There are two different issues coming in there: 1) in very small samples (only a few jobs for a given supplies), you may have a very poor estimate of the supplier's typical complaint ratio, which means they shouldn't be overly penalized for a poor ratio in their first job or two; that might just be bad luck; 2) given two suppliers who actually have equal underlying poor ratios (in the long term, they'll both average 900 complaints per 1000 jobs, say), the one who has done the most jobs is doing more harm ... which you presumably also care about and want to account for. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... The first thing is a statistical problem. The second thing relates to - at a given complaint ratio - how much worse 1000 complaint-ridden jobs is than 500, and how much worse 100 is than 50, and so on. That's not a statistical problem, but something for you to define. You tell us *how much more it matters*. Is it twice as important? Not as much as twice?

Comment: @csetzkorn, do you have ideas about how performance should be weighted with increasing $n$?

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of the problem concerned with ranking suppliers according to the guidelines given could proceed as follows:

Taking $n$ as the number of jobs and $m$ as the number of complaints, multiply the complaint ratio by any increasing function of $m$, say,

$m \;log(m+1) / n$, provided $m >= 0$, and $n > 0$, to order suppliers.

This assumes that the ranking for two suppliers with equal complaint ratios $m/n$ depends solely on the number of complaints received.

For example (using [R](http://www.r-project.org/)):

```
m <- c(0,1,10,100,1000)
n <- c(1,1,10,100,1000)

m/n             ## complaint ratio
[1] 0 1 1 1 1

order(m/n * log(m+1))

[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

As pointed out in the comments, development of a quantitative scale for suppliers relies on understanding how to weight relative performance and account for reduced uncertainty with increasing $n$.

Comment: Why should this work?  What is the justification for it?

Comment: @whuber, taking 1000+ to mean >= 1000, OP suggests that cases with equal m/n should be scaled such that those with smaller n are favoured. This is one way to fulfil that criterion. Any strictly monotonic increasing function of m scaled by 1/n would be equivalent under the interpretation I made. Happy to take suggestions.

Comment: It is important to state your assumptions and your logic within the answer.  In this case I would like to suggest asking the original proposer for clarification, because I suspect the question concerns how to balance the trade-off between the proportion of complaints and the uncertainty associated with small numbers of job executions.  (This question has been asked many times before, in many contexts, but so far without any adequate answer.)

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comments. What alternatives are there? I am sure there is no best answer to this problem ...

Comment: @whuber, I had been thinking about this only in terms of producing a deterministic ranking according to the (incompletely specified) terms of the question. And I failed to adequately explain that. Thanks for the prompt. Answer (and humility) updated.